# How can a class start when I run the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a little game with a square that moves around.Does anyone know how to make the class start when I run the program?

this is the class

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.player = self.canvas.create_rectangle(240, 240, 260, 260, 
        fill="blue", outline="dark blue")
        canvasx = canvas.winfo_width()
        canvasy = canvas.winfo_height()
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Up>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-w>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Down>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-s>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Right>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-d>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-Left>", move)
        canvas.bind_all("<KeyPress-a>", move)
    def move(event):
        if event.keysym == "Up" or event.keysym == "w":
            canvas.move(1, 0, -5)
        elif event.keysym == "Down" or event.keysym == "s":
            canvas.move(1, 0, 5)
        elif event.keysym == "Right" or event.keysym == "d":
            canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
        else:
            canvas.move(1, -5, 0)

canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500, bg="silver")
canvas.pack()
```

this while loop should make the function run, but it doesn't

```
while True:
    Player.__init__
    Player.move
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: Only the imports and the tkinter basics options are missing

Comment: `Player.__init__` doesn't **call** the function itself, and nor is directly calling `__init__` the correct way to create an instance of `Player`. Please read a good book on OOP in Python before attempting to code your own class.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Pygame object move", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  I expect that what you want is called a "sprite".

Comment: A `class` is not an executable entity that one can "start": it's a container for data and methods that work together to encapsulate a programming concept.  You can call a class method ... but you want an independently movable icon.  Work through more game animation tutorials to get the necessary concepts.  You have the basic structure; I expect the work-through will be quick for you.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Player.__init__
Player.move
tk.update()
time.sleep(0.01)
```

is not how you create an instance of a class. When you put `Player.__init__`, you're not actually calling the constructor. You're basically just stating that it exists. Same with `Player.move`. You have to actually call the method. Replace those two lines with this:

```
playerOne = Player(canvas)
playerOne.move()
```

Now `playerOne` is an instance of the `Player` class.

Beyond that, you have an additional problem in the `Player` constructor.

```
def __init__(self, event):
    self.player = self.canvas.create_rectangle(240, 240, 260, 260, 
    fill="blue", outline="dark blue")
```

When you reference `self.canvas`, there is no `self.canvas`. You have to assign it before you can use it. And you don't seem to use `self.player` anywhere. I'm not sure exactly what you're going for with that, but try something like this:

```
def __init__(self, canvas):
    self.canvas = canvas.create_rectangle(240, 240, 260, 260, 
    fill="blue", outline="dark blue")
```

And then replace your `move` method definition with this:

```
def move(event=None):
    if event == None:
        return
    if event.keysym == "Up" or event.keysym == "w":
        canvas.move(1, 0, -5)
    elif event.keysym == "Down" or event.keysym == "s":
        canvas.move(1, 0, 5)
    elif event.keysym == "Right" or event.keysym == "d":
        canvas.move(1, 5, 0)
    else:
        canvas.move(1, -5, 0)
```

Defined outside of your `Player` class.

Comment: File "C:\Users\vitoa\Desktop\tkinter.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.player = self.canvas.create_rectangle(240, 240, 260, 260, fill="blue", outline="dark blue")
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'canvas'

Comment: Did you try to run it?